# unable to receive data from client

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to send two lists and a date value from client to server. I create my url and when I alert it is correct. when I send the data to server I am trying to extract but I don't get my values correctly. here is my code for JQ :

```
 $("#insert").click(function () {

    listofsit = "";
    $(".sel").each(function () {

        listofsit += $(this).val() + ",";

    });
    listofsit += "#";
    //alert(listofsit);

    listofmem = "";
    $(".clsid").each(function () {

        listofmem += $(this).html() + ",";

    });
    listofmem += "#";
    // alert(listofmem);

    var date = $("#date").val();
    var url = "rollcall.aspx?cmd=ins&sitlist=" + listofsit + "&memlist=" + listofmem   +"&date=" + date;
   // alert(url);
    $.post(url, function (d) { alert(d) });
});
```

and here is my C# part:

```
if (cmd == "ins")
{
    mydb db = new mydb();                    

    string[] sitlst = Request.QueryString[1].ToString().Split(',');
    string[] memt = Request.QueryString[2].ToString().Split(',');
    var date = Request["date"];            

    Response.Write("1");
    cmd = "fillgrid";
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put a `#` in to your URL. This will mean that anything after the `#` (`memlist` and `date` parameters) will be considered as a URL fragment, not part of the querystring.

Remove the `#` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. but can i replace # with any other characters ? in order to point out the end of the list. i know it is not necessary but well...

Comment: and yes it was possible, i replaced it with "e". but what is the problem with #. i am not sure i understand.

Comment: Why would that be necessary - the end of the list is just the last item in the list? `#` is a reserved character in a URL for pointing to an anchor within the page.